# When is the "inequality" approach to limits valid?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, inequality

For example, let's say $\lim_{x\to \infty} [g(x)]^{f(x)}=1$ .

If we know that as $x \to \infty$, $h(x)> g(x)$ , we can say that  $\lim_{x\to \infty} [h(x)]^{f(x)}$ equals $\infty$ .

However, I suspect that for this technique to work, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} r^{(n)} (x) >0$ , (where $r(x)=h(x)-g(x)$ ) but I don't know what the minimum value of $n$ would be.

> My questions are:
>
> Can this technique be valid (i.e. can it be applied to any continuous functions $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ )?
>
> If so, was my intuition about the restriction $\lim_{x\to \infty} r^{(n)} (x) >0$ correct?
>
> If so, what would be the minimum value for $n$? If possible, please keep the answers at a Calculus $1$ level. Thanks.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} (g(x))^{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(h(x))^{f(x)}=1$ if $f$ is the constant $0$ function (for example), so you need more assumptions.

Comment: Well let's assume $f(x) \not = 0$ , and you can make any assumption necessary for this to work.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Also, do you think it would be appropriate to tag this as "analysis"?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking. You are stating a "fact", calling it a technique, and then asking something related to whether the fact actually holds. (?) Is your question the following? Assume that $\lim_{x\to \infty} [g(x)]^{f(x)}=1$. Is there an $n$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(h^{(m)}(x)-g^{(m)}(x))>0$ for all $m\le n$ allows us to conclude that $\lim_{x\to \infty} [h(x)]^{f(x)}=+\infty$? If so, what is the least such $n$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I edited the question, is this more clear?

Comment: By the way, no statement like this will be true, unless you impose conditions on $f$. Trivially, you want $f$ not identically zero, but you'd need *much* more.

Comment: And yes your statement of my question was correct.